# Powershell Using Scope Modifier In Invoke-Command For a VM

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, using, invoke-command

I'm trying to pass the value of the variable $DNSClientServerAddr inside an Invoke-Command -VMName. My option is the 'using' scope modifier. I can't seem to pass its value:

```
[int]$NumberOfVMs = Read-Host "NUMBER OF VMs TO BE CONFIGURED"
$VMName = Read-Host "VM NAME PREFIX                "
[int]$VMNameSuffix = Read-Host "STARTING NUMBER               "
$DNSClientServerAddr = Read-Host "DNS CLIENT SERVER IP ADDRESS  "
For ($Count = 1; $Count -le $NumberOfVMs; $Count++, $VMNameSuffix++) {
    $VMNameFull = "$VMName" + "$VMNameSuffix"
    Invoke-Command -VMName $VMNameFull -ScriptBlock {
        $Using:DNSClientServerAddr
        Write-Host $DNSClientServerAddr }
}
```

What I get is always blank when I test to see in Write-Host $DNSClientServerAddr. Does 'using' work with Invoke-Command to a VM in a code as straightforward as this? Or do I really have to use New-PSSession and -ArgumentList?  Also, should Hyper-V be active/installed in the VMs that I'm supposed to configure?

By the way, I'm using Powershell version 5.1.

Thank you!

Comment: the syntax is incorrect in your `for` loop. It should be: `For ($Count = 1; $Count -le $NumberOfVMs; $Count++)`. As for your variable inside your scriptblock, the first one is correcting using the `$using:`  scope, but the second one isnt. You still need to specify it as a remote variable.

Answer (score 0):

`$DNSClientServerAddr` is not defined in your remote session.
You can use a local variable through `$Using` directly like this:

```
Invoke-Command -VMName $VMNameFull -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host $Using:DNSClientServerAddr
}
```

You could also assign the variable so it become native to the remote session and discard the need of using the  `$using` scope modifier but you still have to do an initial assignment.

```
Invoke-Command -VMName $VMNameFull -ScriptBlock {
    $DNSClientServerAddr = $Using:DNSClientServerAddr
    Write-Host $DNSClientServerAddr
}
```

**References**

[About_remote_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.2#using-local-variables)

[About_Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.2)

[About_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2)